Telegram bot - conversationHandler is not able to keep state Selecting conversation (###, ###) with state None
I am using python-telegram-bot to create a telegram bot managed through a FastAPI app, here is my code
import asyncio
import logging
import re
import os
from utils import *
import uuid
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from pydantic import BaseModel
from telegram import Update, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.constants import ParseMode
from telegram.ext import (Application, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, 
                          ContextTypes, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext,
                          ConversationHandler)
from telegram.error import RetryAfter
from config import *
from content import joinUsBotContent, COMMANDS, SEPARATOR_LINE

# Initialize FastAPI app    
app = FastAPI()

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.DEBUG
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Specifically set the logging level for the telegram and telegram.ext modules
logging.getLogger('telegram').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('telegram.ext').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Initialize the bot application
telegram_app = Application.builder().token(TELEGRAM_TOKEN).build()

# User data storage
user_data = {}

# Define states
ASK_NEW_OR_RETURNING_USER, ASK_GUIDELINES, ASK_PLATFORM, \
    ASK_VOICE_MSG, ASK_PROFILE_LINK, ASK_VERIFICATION_POST = range(1, 7)

class WebhookBody(BaseModel):
    update_id: int
    message: dict = None
    edited_message: dict = None
    channel_post: dict = None
    edited_channel_post: dict = None
    inline_query: dict = None
    chosen_inline_result: dict = None
    callback_query: dict = None

async def set_commands(bot):
    await bot.set_my_commands(COMMANDS)


async def set_webhook_with_retries(bot, webhook_url, retries=5, delay=1):
    for attempt in range(retries):
        try:
            await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
            await bot.set_webhook(webhook_url)
            return
        except RetryAfter as e:
            retry_after = e.retry_after or delay
            logger.warning(f"Rate limit exceeded. Retrying in {retry_after} seconds...")
            await asyncio.sleep(retry_after)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Failed to set webhook: {e}")
            await asyncio.sleep(delay)


@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup():
    # Add conversation handler with the states 
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states={
            ASK_NEW_OR_RETURNING_USER: [CallbackQueryHandler(ask_new_or_returning_user, pattern='^(new_user|returning_user)$')],
            ASK_GUIDELINES: [CallbackQueryHandler(
                                ask_guidelines,
                                pattern='^(watchedInstructionsVid|didNotWatchInstructionsVid)$'
                            )],
            ASK_PLATFORM: [CallbackQueryHandler(ask_platform,
                                                pattern='^(twitter|facebook|tiktok)$')],
            ASK_VOICE_MSG: [MessageHandler(filters.VOICE, ask_voice_msg)],
            ASK_PROFILE_LINK: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, ask_profile_link)],
            ASK_VERIFICATION_POST: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, ask_verification_post_link)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
        per_message=False,
        per_chat=True,
        name="newMemberConvHandler"
    )
    telegram_app.add_handler(conv_handler)

    # Handle the case when a user sends /start but they're not in a conversation
    telegram_app.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))

    # Ensure no webhook is set before starting
    bot = telegram_app.bot
    #await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    # Set the webhook
    webhook_url = f"{SERVER_URL}/webhook"  # Replace with your webhook URL
    await set_webhook_with_retries(bot, webhook_url)
    await telegram_app.initialize()     
    # Set the command menu
    await set_commands(bot)
    
"""
@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown_event():
    await telegram_app.shutdown()
"""

@app.get('/')
def welcome():
    return {"Welcome to the membership bot"}

@app.post('/webhook')
async def webhook(request: Request):
    update = Update.de_json(await request.json(), telegram_app.bot)
    await telegram_app.process_update(update)
    return {"ok": True}

async def get_chat_id(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    if chat_id not in user_data:
        unique_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        user_data[chat_id] = unique_id
        
        await update.message.reply_text(f"Welcome! Your unique ID is: {unique_id}")
    else:
        await update.message.reply_text(f"Your unique ID is: {user_data[chat_id]}")

async def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    logger.info("0. start")
    user = update.message.from_user
    telegram_username = user.username
    telegram_id = user.id
    logger.info("0.1")
    # Store the user details in the context
    context.user_data['telegram_username'] = telegram_username
    context.user_data['telegram_id'] = telegram_id
    logger.info("0.2")
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton(joinUsBotContent["newMember"], callback_data='new_user')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton(joinUsBotContent["changeAccount"], callback_data='returning_user')],        
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    await update.message.reply_text(
        joinUsBotContent["startupOptions"],
        reply_markup=reply_markup
    )
    logger.info("0.3")
    return ASK_NEW_OR_RETURNING_USER

async def ask_new_or_returning_user(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    logger.info("1. ask_new_or_returning_user")
    query = update.callback_query
    try:
        await query.answer()
        logger.info("1.2")
        if query.data == 'new_user':
            await query.message.reply_text(text=joinUsBotContent["introVid"])
            with open(joinUsBotContent["instructionsVidPath"], "rb") as instructionsVid:
                await query.message.reply_video(instructionsVid)
            yesNoKeyboard = [
                [InlineKeyboardButton(joinUsBotContent["yes"], callback_data='watchedInstructionsVid')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton(joinUsBotContent["no"], callback_data='didNotWatchInstructionsVid')],
            ]
            yes_no_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(yesNoKeyboard)
            await query.message.reply_text(
                joinUsBotContent["didYouWatchTheVid"],
                reply_markup=yes_no_markup
            )
            logger.info("1.3")
            return ASK_GUIDELINES
        elif query.data == 'returning_user':
            await query.message.reply_text(text=joinUsBotContent["contactAdmin"])
            logger.info("returning user, ending conversation...")
            return ConversationHandler.END
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in ask_new_or_returning_user: {e}")
        return ASK_NEW_OR_RETURNING_USER

async def ask_guidelines(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    logger.info("2. ask_guidelines")
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    logger.info("2.1")
    if query.data == 'didNotWatchInstructionsVid':
        await query.message.reply_text(joinUsBotContent["watchTillEndWarning"])
        yesNoKeyboard = [
            [InlineKeyboardButton(joinUsBotContent["yes"], callback_data='watchedInstructionsVid')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton(joinUsBotContent["no"], callback_data='didNotWatchInstructionsVid')],
        ]
        yes_no_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(yesNoKeyboard)
        await query.message.reply_text(
            joinUsBotContent["didYouWatchTheVid"],
            reply_markup=yes_no_markup
        )
        return ASK_GUIDELINES
    elif query.data == 'watchedInstructionsVid':
        logger.info("2.3")
        selectPlatformKeyboard = [
            [InlineKeyboardButton(joinUsBotContent["twitter"], callback_data='twitter')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton(joinUsBotContent["facebook"], callback_data='facebook')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton(joinUsBotContent["tiktok"], callback_data='tiktok')],
        ]
        platforms_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(selectPlatformKeyboard)
        await query.message.reply_text(
            joinUsBotContent["selectPlatform"],
            reply_markup=platforms_markup
        )
        logger.info("2.4")
        return ASK_PLATFORM

async def ask_platform(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    logger.info("3. ask_platform")
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    logger.info("3.1")
    if query.data == 'twitter':
        context.user_data['platform_code'] = 0
    elif query.data == 'facebook':
        context.user_data['platform_code'] = 1
    elif query.data == 'tiktok':
        context.user_data['platform_code'] = 2
    
    await query.message.reply_text(joinUsBotContent["instruction1"])
    with open(joinUsBotContent["recordButtonIllustraionImgPath"], "rb") as photo:
        await query.message.reply_photo(photo)
    logger.info("3.2")
    return ASK_VOICE_MSG

async def ask_voice_msg(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    # Check if the message contains a voice note
    logger.info("4. ask_voice_msg")
    voice_msg = update.message.voice
    logger.info("4.1")
    if voice_msg is not None:
        logger.info("4.2")
        context.user_data['chat_id'] = update.message.chat_id
        context.user_data['voice_verification_msg_id'] = update.message.message_id

        await update.message.reply_text(joinUsBotContent["instruction2"])
        await update.message.reply_text(joinUsBotContent["instruction3"],
                                        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML,)
        await update.message.reply_text(joinUsBotContent["instruction4"])
        await update.message.reply_text(joinUsBotContent["instruction5"])
        await update.message.reply_text(joinUsBotContent["instruction6"])
        # Request profile link
        await update.message.reply_text(joinUsBotContent["instruction7"])
        # send the voice msg to new users channel! but apply some verifications first
        logger.info("4.3")
        return ASK_PROFILE_LINK
    else:
        await update.message.reply_text(joinUsBotContent["voiceDidNotReceived"])
        # Optionally, you can return to the same state to retry
        return ASK_VOICE_MSG

# Define function to handle name response
async def ask_profile_link(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    logger.info("5. ask_profile_link")
    message_text = update.message.text
    # Basic verification for Twitter link
    #twitter_link_regex = r"^https?:\/\/(www\.)?(twitter|x)\.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15}(\/)?$"
    https_regex = re.compile(r"^https:\/\/.*")
    logger.info("5.1")
    if re.match(https_regex, message_text):
        context.user_data['social_media_account'] = message_text
        userVerificationCode = generate_random_code(length=6)
        context.user_data['user_verification_code'] = userVerificationCode
        await update.message.reply_text(joinUsBotContent["validAccountLinkReceived"])
        logger.info("5.2")
        await update.message.reply_text(
            f'{joinUsBotContent["instruction8"]} {userVerificationCode} {joinUsBotContent["instruction8part2"]}')
        logger.info("5.3")
        return ASK_VERIFICATION_POST
    else:
        await update.message.reply_text(joinUsBotContent["invalidAccountLinkReceived"])
        return ASK_PROFILE_LINK

async def ask_verification_post_link(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    message_text = update.message.text
    # Basic verification for valid link
    https_regex = re.compile(r"^https:\/\/.*")
    if https_regex.match(message_text):
        context.user_data['verification_post_link'] = message_text
        await update.message.reply_text(joinUsBotContent["instruction9"],
                                        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML,)
        await update.message.reply_text(joinUsBotContent["instruction10"])
        await update.message.reply_text(joinUsBotContent["instruction11"])
        # End the conversation
        await end_conversation(context=context)
    else:
        await update.message.reply_text(joinUsBotContent["invalidPostLinkReceived"])
        return ASK_VERIFICATION_POST

# Define the cancel function
async def cancel(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    await update.message.reply_text(joinUsBotContent["cancelMsg"])
    logger.info("fal back called, ending conversation... State will be lost!")
    return ConversationHandler.END

# Handler to end conversation and send message to channel
async def end_conversation(context: CallbackContext):
    try:
        user_card = generate_user_card(context.user_data)
                
        # Ensure the bot is sending to the correct chat ID
        response = await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=NEW_MEMBERS_CHANNEL, text=user_card, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
        
        # Forward the voice verification message
        await context.bot.forward_message(
            chat_id=NEW_MEMBERS_CHANNEL,
            from_chat_id=context.user_data["chat_id"],
            message_id=context.user_data["voice_verification_msg_id"]
        )

        # send a separator dash line
        response = await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=NEW_MEMBERS_CHANNEL, text=SEPARATOR_LINE)
        logger.info("conversation completed successfully, ending it...")
    except Exception as e:
        # Log any exception that occurs
        logger.error("Error sending message: %s", str(e))
        
    return ConversationHandler.END

When user chooses one of the inline options or send a message to the bot, the logs states
telegram.ext.ConversationHandler - DEBUG - Selecting conversation (1234, 1234) with state None

when I repeat after 2-3 times, the handler picks up the correct state.
Why isn't the state kept/tracked correctly from the first time and how to fix it?
Turned on debug mode to see logs, and tried persistence but it didn't help

When asked Gemine, it suggested that the cause is per_message=False: This setting tells the ConversationHandler to not track the conversation state for every message update. It only tracks the state when a callback query is received. per_message=False: This setting tells the ConversationHandler to not track the conversation state for every message update. It only tracks the state when a callback query is received. But when I tried it, it didn't help

please provide additional context on your setup. how is "app" defined? when does on_startup run? Only once on startup or are you using a serverless setup?

added. It is a FastAPI app and Startup is called on app loading the first time

please also add how you run the app - so that one can try to reproduce locally

added complete code

app is run using gunicorn

okay, gunicorn is probably the curprit here. I'm not very familiar with ASGI webservers but AFAIK it will start multiple instances of the app on demand, right? as the in-memory data will not be shared between them, the conversation will be tracked independently in each worker
